# Variance of Sample Mean for a Positively Correlated Sample

Tags: correlation, mean, convergence, sample

Suppose we have a sample of n observations which are positively correlated with correlation matrix given by $\sigma^2$ as diagonal entries and $a\sigma^2$ as off-diagonal entries. Then we should get that the variance of the sample mean is $\sigma^2(1/n + a(1-1/n))$ which tends to $a\sigma^2$ as $n\to \infty$. What does this intuitively mean for estimation of the mean from this sample? I understand that the sample mean now does not converge in probability to the true mean of the distribution, but not so much what the limit of the variance of it implies.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=(X_1, \dotsc, X_n)^T$ which has covariance matrix $\Sigma=\sigma^2 R$ where the correlation matrix $R$ has diagonal elements $R_{ii}=1$ and off-diagonals $R_{ij}=a, i\not = j$ (here $-\frac1{n-1}\le a \le 1$, see [Intuition for near-decorrelation through centering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208776/intuition-for-near-decorrelation-through-centering).)

Then $\bar{X}=\frac1n 1^T X$ (where $1$ is a column vector of all ones.) The rest is linear algebra, using the formula
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}
  \V [a^T X] = a^T \V[ X] a  \qquad\text{which is the linear algebra version of $\V(a X) = a^2 \V X$. }
$$
So
$$
\V \bar{X} = \V \frac1n 1^T X = (\frac1n)^2 1^T \Sigma 1 =\\
(\frac1n)^2 \sigma^2 1^T R 1=(\frac1n)^2 \sigma^2 \sum_i\sum_j R_{ij} =\\
\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\left( 1+(n-1)a \right)
$$
Check what happens with this formula if you use the smallest (or largest) possible value for $a$.